# Setting text of a label in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Abstract:
I'm trying to set an error message if a choice has not been made by a drop down menu.

Details:

Here's my dd with a call to a javascript function:

```
<%:Html.DropDownListFor(r => Model.TypeId, TypeItems, new { @class="stretchInput", @onblur = "errorCheck"})%>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("blur", "select[name=TypeId]",
        function errorCheck() {
            var errId = 'Type not chosen. Please choose from the menu.';
            if (document.getElementById('TypeId').selectedIndex == 0) {
                document.getElementById("DetailsError").visibility = 'visible';
                document.getElementById("DetailsError").innerHTML = errId;
            }
        });
</script>
```

Here's the label that I want to change the value of:

```
<td><asp:Label ID="DetailsError" runat="server" CssClass="errorMsg" Text="testing" Visible="false"></asp:Label></td>
```

I'm aware that it's an ASP control, by the way. I've tried `HTML label` and get the same result.

All I'm trying to set the label's text with my error message. It appears that nothing I do affects the label in any way.

What am I missing?

Comment: View the generated source of the page, look for the label. What do you see?

Comment: <span id="MainContent_DetailsError" class="errorMsg">testing</span>

Comment: BINGO!  I prefixed DetailsError with 'MainContent_' and it works.  Thanks epascarello!

Answer (score 2):

If you just have to use the label to display error messages from JavaScript, i.e. the control has no server side relevance, you may use `<span id="DetailsError">`.

Or

You may use the `<%=DetailsError.ClientID%>` everywhere in the HTML / JS code where you want to use `DetailsError`.

For e.g.:

```
document.getElementById("<%=DetailsError.ClientID%>").innerHTML = errId;
```

> Please take this as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution.